# Creating a seperate Authentication Server for my spring boot application

Tags: spring-boot

I am trying to create a spring boot application and secure it using Spring security. If do not want to  include the starter-security package in my application, instead I want to create a seperate Spring boot application which will only take care of Authentication.

My question is how to call the backend-apis via client. Should I call the Authentication server first from client(so all my http calls will have authentication server ip and port), or should I call main application first and write a filter to redirect every call to authentication server first? or What approach should I take

Any suggestion is appreciated!

Comment: So, it isn’t quite understandable. Do you want to implement your own identity provider or what? What are the api’s calls in your case? Could you provide more information about your question?

Comment: I want to implement a seperate server for authentication using spring security, so there will be a client, an auth server, and the backend services

Comment: If you need just authorisation service you can use it from spring security. It provides AuthzService by annotation @AuthorizationServer, but pay attention there isn’t implementation for OIDC, just Auth2.0

Comment: Just need a simple flow to understand it better, Client -> Authorization Server -> Backend ........ OR ...... Client -> Backend --- Redirects to auth server---> Authorization Server -> Backend

Comment: If you want to implement identity provider it is a big deal. If you want to receive an access to your resource service for your application without the participation of the end user in that case you can authenticate directly to authorisation service of your resource service. Actually, you have provided a pretty less information than it is necessary to define the architecture approach.

Comment: For now I have made a seperate authentication server using Eureka and Zuul proxy servers. The client will call this server and the zuul proxy will redirect it to particular microservice using url pattern.